# How to forbid the access to file from other processes in python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a file, and several processes which can operate on it. For simplicity let us assume that each process runs the same script:

```
with open("file.txt", "r+") as file:
    data = file.read()
    data = data + "Hello\n"
    file.seek(0)
    file.write(data)
```

I assume that such a way of file access allows several processes to modify the same file, what results in improper writing (for instance, three processes could get "HeHello\nHello\nllo" as a result). Is there any way to forbid access to the file for some time and still be able to read and write from there from the current process?

Comment: Have you looked at this post yet? [Multiple processes write a same CSV file, how to avoid conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19830928/15489646)